# Stuck on blank screen while closing the CustomTabs in Android (xamarin forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, openid-connect

I have implemented OIDC in the Xamarin.Forms app and I am stuck on blank screen while closing the CustomTabs on specific device (e.g. **Huawei Y6 2019**)

[image]

**Here is Activity class** :

```
[Activity(Label = "OidcCallbackActivity")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
        DataScheme = "myapp")]
public class OidcCallbackActivity : Activity
{
    public static event Action<string> Callbacks;

    public OidcCallbackActivity()
    {
        Log.Debug("OidcCallbackActivity", "constructing OidcCallbackActivity");
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Callbacks?.Invoke(Intent.DataString);

        Finish();

        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }
}
```

**Here is the code to launch the browser** :

```
public Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsync(BrowserOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var task = new TaskCompletionSource<BrowserResult>();

    var builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder(_manager.Session)
        .SetToolbarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(1, 45, 152, 102))
        .SetShowTitle(true)
        .EnableUrlBarHiding();

    var customTabsIntent = builder.Build();
       
    callback = url =>
    {
       OidcCallbackActivity.Callbacks -= callback;

       task.SetResult(new BrowserResult()
       {
          Response = url
       });                
    };

    OidcCallbackActivity.Callbacks += callback;

    customTabsIntent.LaunchUrl(_context, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(options.StartUrl));            

    return task.Task;
}
```

Comment: Try this in your Activity class, you may missed DataHost value.

[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
            Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
            DataScheme = "myapp",
            DataHost = "callback")]